# Undefined method `belong_to' for RSpec, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm getting an error as follows when running rspec tests.

```
Failure/Error: it { should belong_to :user }

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `belong_to' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UserEventFavorite:0x007fd0fa9c66c0>
```

I've identified that belong_to is specific to Shoulda Matcher. However, I should have Shoulda Matcher installed correctly as can be seen from `spec_helper.rb` and `rails_helper.rb` below. Can someone tell me what I am missing here?

spec_helper.rb

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'shoulda/matchers'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups
  config.include RSpec::RequestDescriber, type: :request
  config.before :all do
    FactoryGirl.factories.clear
    FactoryGirl.reload
  end
  config.before :suite do
    DatabaseRewinder.clean_all
  end
  config.after :each do
    DatabaseRewinder.clean
  end
  Autodoc.configuration.toc = true
end
```

rails_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include RSpec::RequestDescriber, type: :request
  # config.include RequestHelpers, type: :request
  # config.include RequestMacros, type: :request

  config.before :all do
    FactoryGirl.factories.clear
    FactoryGirl.find_definitions
    FactoryGirl.reload
  end

  config.before :suite do
    DatabaseRewinder.clean_all
  end

  config.after :each do
    DatabaseRewinder.clean
  end

  Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
    config.integrate do |with|
      with.test_framework :rspec
      with.library :rails
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the spec code:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rails_helper'
describe UserEventFavorite do
  let(:user_event_favorite) { FactoryGirl.build :user_event_favorite }
  subject { user_event_favorite }

  it { should respond_to :user_id }
  it { should respond_to :event_id }

  it { should belong_to :user }
  it { should belong_to :event }
end
```

Comment: Can you add the spec code, please?

Comment: My bad! Just added.

Comment: Could that be, that you forgot to `require 'rails_helper'` in the spec file?

Comment: I have both `require 'spec_helper'` and `require 'rails_helper'`.

Answer (score 5):

I figured out the problem.

I needed to add `type: :model` in my spec code. The working solution is:

```
describe UserEventFavorite, type: :model do
  let(:user_event_favorite) { FactoryGirl.build :user_event_favorite }
  subject { user_event_favorite }

  it { should respond_to :user_id }
  it { should respond_to :event_id }

  it { should belong_to :user }
  it { should belong_to :event }
end
```

instead of

```
describe UserEventFavorite do
  let(:user_event_favorite) { FactoryGirl.build :user_event_favorite }
  subject { user_event_favorite }

  it { should respond_to :user_id }
  it { should respond_to :event_id }

  it { should belong_to :user }
  it { should belong_to :event }
end
```